# .NET Core 2.2 - Entity Framework - Custom Assign [NotMapped] Model Attribute w/ DbSet.FromSql()

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .NET Core 2.2 API project. I'm trying to set up an EF Model class with custom attributes, which are not mapped directly to fields in the table, will *usually* be `NULL`, but in one single instance will be custom-assigned.

Here is (conceptually) my model:

```
public class SomeObject {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string CustomField1 { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string CustomField2 { get; set; }
}
```

Elsewhere in the code, I have what essentially amounts to this:

```
return SomeObjects
            .FromSql($@"select *, <custom mapping here> as CustomField1, <custom mapping here> as CustomField2 from [table name]")
```

I was hoping the mapper would just kind of figure it out under-the-hood based on field names matching, but that doesn't work.

Alternatively, I was hoping for something the `map()` method in Ruby on Rails or Laravel, where I could do something like this:

```
return SomeObjects
            .FromSql($@"select *, <custom mapping here> as CustomField1, <custom mapping here> as CustomField2 from [table name]")
            .Map( o => { o.CustomField1 = CustomField1, o.CustomField2 = CustomField2 });
```

I wouldn't be surprised if it exists and I'm just missing it. I haven't been able to find any documentation on it, but maybe I'm just not googling the right things.

Thoughts?

Comment: `[NotMapped]` tells EF: "Hey man, under no circumstances should you touch this property."

Comment: Then is there a way that I'm missing to have it not update the database with those two fields, not generate new migrations with them, yet still allow me to set them on the way out of the database?

Comment: @Moho has the right idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining a subtype with the additional `CustomFieldX` properties that inherits from the entity type `SomeObjects` to leverage the common properties and mappings.  I abhor hard-coding SQL (defeats one of the main purposes of an ORM) and would prefer a view or stored procedure to which you can then map the subtype.

Comment: Yeah this is probably the best way to do it usually. Doesn't really work with my problem for a few reasons but I found a different workaround by basically just editing the generated migration files manually.